# Choosing right trimmer and capacitor in LM317 circuit

Tags: power-supply, potentiometer, lm317

I am working on stable, low ripple +22V power supply for TLC5940 IC. I am working a circuit based on the model of Texas Instrument's LM371 circuit [image: datasheet's diagram, page 7]. Now, what kind of R2 and CADJ should I use for this circuit. Is Bourn's 3362 Potentiometer right choice for this task and how should I connect it to circuit, since it has three terminals. And, what kind of capacitor should I use for CADJ. I am working in Eagle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CADJ use an electrolytic capacitor of 4.7 to 22 microfarads (TI used 10 microfarads for testing electrical characteristics of LM317).

Check Figure 3 / page 8 in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf).

Here is how to connect the potentiometer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWfXFN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By the way, you can use a 3.9 kiloohms resistor instead of potentiometer or trimmer. You'll get almost 22 V.

Comment: True about fixed resistor instead of pot, but I've got a grip very bargain Burr Brown's 3326 series.

Comment: No matter how good a bargain you can get on pots, a fixed resistor will be cheaper, smaller and more reliable. Also, you don't say how precise you need the voltage to be. If you must use an adjustment pot, using a 5K pot as shown above will allow fairly coarse control of the output voltage, limited by your ability to make fine adjustments. You might do better to use a 3.48k resistor in series with a 1 k  pot.